# Nestjs: Helmetjs x-frame-option not working live but working in local

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nestjs-config

I install helmetjs and test in local is working fine and prevent clickjacking. Same code push into live clickjack prevent not working and x-frame option not visible in network response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Who is your hosting provider? They might be stripping out the header.

Comment: Thank you @Kenneth, web server is blocked x-frame-option.